# Is this set open? From topology without tears book

Tags: general-topology

This question is from "topology without tears" book, page 30. Example 1.2.3

> $\{1\}$ has as complement $\mathbb{N}\setminus \{1\}$ , so it is not finite . ($\mathbb{N}$ is set of natural numbers with the cofinite topology)
>   Then the book concludes that $\{1\}$ is not open!?

My question is : where this conclusion comes from?
Does it mean that if complement of a set is infinite then that set is not open?

Comment: well, what topology has $\mathbb{N}$ equipped on it?

Comment: For example, if $\mathbb{N}$ has the COFINITE topology on it (which seems the case) then by definition of cofinite topology, a subset whose complementary is NOT finite, then it is NOT open. But still, it depends on your hypothesis

Comment: Perfect!  You are right.  This is topology: t =$ \ emptyset$ union S.  S is $\subset {N} such that N - is finite

Comment: hope it's clear now, cofinite topology describe precisely what are opens and what are NOT. you just need to check wether your set satisfies the condition or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpfull if you stated the complete example, especially the topology would be helpfull, just like Riccardo asked.

Now I looked up the book and it says: the topology consists of each subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that the complement of $S$ is a finite set. Clearly $\mathbb{N}\backslash \{1\}$ is an infinite set, hence $\{1\}$ cannot be open.